# error: declaration of 'operator,' as non-function

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, opl

I'm having an error in my compile that I can't quite figure out. I'm a C coder, usually, and I've only started converting my entire program to use C++. So, I've renamed my C file to a CC (cross-compile) and usually, I only have to edit errors by hand. However, this one is a mystery to me - not sure if this is a C++ism or not.

It's an OPL player for the interested.

The following code in question:

```
static void LoadOperatorData(int operator, const genmidi_op_t *data, bool max_level)
{
    int level;

// The scale and level fields must be combined for the level register.
// For the carrier wave we always set the maximum level.

    level = (data->scale & 0xc0) | (data->level & 0x3f);

    if (max_level)
    {
      level |= 0x3f;
    }

   OPL_WriteRegister(OPL_REGS_LEVEL + operator, level);
   OPL_WriteRegister(OPL_REGS_TREMOLO + operator, data->tremolo);
   OPL_WriteRegister(OPL_REGS_ATTACK + operator, data->attack);
   OPL_WriteRegister(OPL_REGS_SUSTAIN + operator, data->sustain);
   OPL_WriteRegister(OPL_REGS_WAVEFORM + operator, data->waveform);
}
```

I am getting a host of errors with this codeblock:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBQDJ.jpg

So it seems I am not converting this to C++ properly. If I can kindly ask someone to write it the correct way and explain it to me, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!
~Coraline

Comment: Can you please tell us which lines are numbered 42, 44 and 50?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WHf5Q3g.jpg (sorry about that!) :/

Comment: could it be that operator is a keyword (I'm not a c/c++ guy)? try renaming it to something else

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware but in C++ we can overload certain operators. To define a new function for the addition operator, we use the method signature as `return_type operator+(max_2_arguments)`. Hence operator is a keyword and CAN'T be used as a variable name

Comment: Try this out and update me for the errors.

Comment: Akash: thank you, but what am I supposed to be adding/removing exactly to the codeblock? =)

Comment: Yes, `operator` is a keyword in C++ (and not in C). Use a different identifier.

Comment: Your IDE actually converted keywords to navy blue color. Didn't you notice?

Comment: @Cora please notify me next time using @AkashAggarwal.
Change your variable name `int operator` to something else like `int opr`

Comment: Also when you've done so, let me know if there are further errors. If not, I'd like to post this as an answer so you can accept it(which adds to my reputation on this network).

Answer (score 3):

`operator` is a reserved word in C++ (used for overloading operators), so you can't have a parameter or variable named `operator`.  Rename `operator` to something else.